# Redirect non www to www, but its only working for home page

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have done non www to www redirection for my site but only home page is working fine but category page is not showing redirection from non www to www.
This is wordpress based website.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So do you getting 404 on category pages? Also please paste your .htaccess code which you have set for redirection.

Comment: i am not getting 404 error page. when i click on category button, site will open as www version but when i open same link without www, it will not redirect to www version.

Comment: can you please put code which you are using for redirection?

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: posting your .htaccess file contents might help

Comment: @kmurugesh - please use following code to redirect :                 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

   # END WordPress
   # Redirect 301  
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: @helping hands that code is working i tried it, but problem is same .. its not working for sub category pages

Comment: @kmurugesh - I think you will find solution here : https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do my non-WWW to WWW redirects.

In the .htaccess file, add this:

```
# REDIRECT NON-WWW TO WWW
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Replace "domain" and "com" as necessary for your site.

Comment: I actually tried all these kind of commands but still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the Home URL and Site URL of your domain with www in the Dashboard >> Settings >> General ?
If yes, then the non-www site will always get redirected to www site.